# What tool exists to compile C++2011 code for Windows target?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, c++11, cross-compiling

I created a program in C++2011 that actually uses features of C++2011: `mutex`, `unique_lock`, `condition_variable`, `future` and `async`.

I've tested it on Debian Linux 64 bits box, and it compiles and runs like a charm.

---

Now, I want to compile it for Windows.

I tried Visual C++ Express 2010, but it does not have support for the new features of C++. (The Beta for Visual C++/Studio 2012 only runs on Windows 8.)

I tried cross compiling with mingw-g++ (4.6), but it looks like these new features are not supported for the Windows target. (Although they are supported for g++-4.6 for Linux target).

Is there any (free?) solution as of today to compile a C++2011 program for Windows target?

Comment: And that's why you shouldn't rush to use new standard...

Comment: Is there a technical problem with running the VS 2012 beta in a Win8 beta virtual machine?

Comment: Visual Studio S2012 (VS11) runs on windows 7.

Comment: @SigTerm Using all of these features, right here, embedded into the language and standard library is damn tempting: it speeds up programming. I spend more time adapting the program to WinApi calls (and discovering a cin/cout issue) than writing it in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried it yet, but this quote from the project site sounds promising:

"Builds support the following technologies:

```
OpenMP
LTO
Graphite
std_threads
std_atomics
```

..."

http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/

hope this helps

Comment: Downloaded version 4.6. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

My (commercial) [Just::Thread library](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) provides `std::thread`, `std::mutex` and friends for MSVC 2005/2008/2010 and the TDM port of mingw-gcc 4.5/4.6 on Windows. It's not free, though.

Alternatively, look for a build of gcc 4.7 for mingw. Support for the thread library on Windows is supposed to be available out-of-the-box with gcc 4.7, but it's not officially released yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant that mingw support for gcc 4.7 wasn't out yet, but gcc 4.7 is out: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-03/msg00347.html

Comment: I meant I haven't seen an official mingw gcc 4.7 yet.

Comment: It looks like the google mingw-builds page has gcc 4.7 release builds now. http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/list